# Jquery function single quotes ignored

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick, quotes

i have this function

```
    function getTextfieldonly(fieldName, id) {
        var option = jQuery('#'+fieldName+'_textfield').val();
        if (option != "") {
        $('.'+fieldName+'_ul').append('<li class="'+fieldName+'_item">'+option+'<span onclick="removeSelected($(this),'+fieldName+')" class="reLef buttonleistungspktr '+fieldName+'_button2"></span></li>');
        $('#'+fieldName+'_list').prepend('<option selected="selected" value="'+option+'">'+option+'</option>');
        }else {return false}
    };
```

in row 4 i´m appending an li with a span inside

```
.append('<li class="'+fieldName+'_item">'+option+'<span onclick="removeSelected($(this),'+fieldName+')" class="reLef buttonleistungspktr '+fieldName+'_button2"></span></li>');
```

if the fieldName parameter is for example "foo"

I want the onclick inside the appended span to look like

```
onclick="removeSelected($(this),'foo')"
```

but it´s rendered like

```
onclick="removeSelected($(this),foo)"
```

So where did the singlequotes go ? 
I need them to be there and I can´t figure out how.

anyone has an idea ? thanks in advance

Comment: The better alternative would be to bind the handler with jQuery instead of using inline event handlers. *where did the singlequotes go*: There never have been single quotes. In `[...] ,'+fieldName+')" [...]`, the single quotes denote the string literals you prepend and append to `fieldName`.

Comment: You should avoid writing inline javascript. That is a terrible security issue. It's so bad that techniques are started to being added to force the browser to reject it http://www.w3.org/TR/CSP/

Comment: thanks for your advices, the other way of solving this was to update the div with items with ajax and bit of controller code and inside the div a ready-function with click(function(){eventhandlinghere})

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
<span onclick="removeSelected($(this),'+fieldName+')"
```

to

```
<span onclick="removeSelected($(this),\''+fieldName+'\')"
```

You need to escape the single quotes